# Free memory after malloc in a loop

Tags: c++, malloc, free

I got some memory allocated in a loop - how to free it when I am done with tr_data variable ?
(I am fairly new to C++)

```
    #define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))

    struct svm_problem tr_data;
    tr_data.l = (int) prm_num_samples_anchored.array[bar];

    tr_data.y = Malloc(double, tr_data.l);
    tr_data.x = Malloc(struct svm_node*, tr_data.l);



    for (int row = 0; row < tr_data.l; row++)
    {
        tr_data.y[row] = ta0.array[bar-row-1];

        //leak
        svm_node* tr_data_x_onerow = Malloc(svm_node, num_features+1);  

        tr_data_x_onerow[0].index = 1; tr_data_x_onerow[0].value = in0.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[1].index = 2; tr_data_x_onerow[1].value = in1.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[2].index = 3; tr_data_x_onerow[2].value = in2.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[3].index = 4; tr_data_x_onerow[3].value = in3.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[4].index = 5; tr_data_x_onerow[4].value = in4.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[5].index = 6; tr_data_x_onerow[5].value = in5.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[6].index = 7; tr_data_x_onerow[6].value = in6.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[7].index = 8; tr_data_x_onerow[7].value = in7.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[8].index = 9; tr_data_x_onerow[8].value = in8.array[bar-row-1];    tr_data_x_onerow[9].index = 10;

        tr_data_x_onerow[num_features].index = -1;      //Each row of properties should be terminated with a -1 according to the readme

        tr_data.x[row] = tr_data_x_onerow;

    }
```

... few operation on tr_data
... and this does not work

```
    for (int row = 0; row <tr_data.l; row++)
    {
        free(tr_data_x_onerow);
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to `free(tr_data.x[row]);` in your second loop, since `svm_node* tr_data_x_onerow` is only available inside the first loop.

Comment: As a sidenote, you should not use malloc / free in C++
(prefer shared pointers or else new / delete)

Comment: @Zermingore new/delete is only gradually better (it should be new[]/delete[]). In C++, you should never allocate arrays dynamically, and there is no need for it. Just use `std::vector`

Comment: @Jens I completely agree
The first line of the code sample just scared me

Comment: @Zermingore Yeah, even C has inline functions since 16 years (C99). C programmers seem to be the most change-resistent people on earth...

Comment: @Jens Make that "programmers" (no "C"). It took four decades for garbage collection to become mainstream, and with the advent of `lambda`, we have finally reached the 1930's. I use an editor from the eighties and run my programs in an emulator of a terminal from the seventies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (int row = 0; row <tr_data.l; row++)
{
    free(tr_data.x[row]);
}
```

But please, just don't do this. This is C++. Use a vector or some other sane collection.

Comment: I would if I could - this data format is used by library I use.

Comment: You can use the same data format and not call `malloc`. For example, you can make a C++ class that uses sane containers to hold the data but still creates this same structure with pointers into your containers. (Unless the library can call `free` or `realloc`. Then you're screwed.)